# How to restrict command usage to discord user IDs (Discord js)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to create a discord bot simply for the purpose of the say command. I want it to return a message and delete the command message, but keep the command restricted to certain users. I have a working say and delete, however I do not know how to restrict the usage. I've set a const that has the two user IDs I'd like to restrict it to, but I am unsure how to restrict the entire bot to those IDs. Any help would be appreciated.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")

const TOKEN = "---"

prefix = "."

const adminIDs = ["-", "-"]

const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [
        "GUILDS",
        "GUILD_MESSAGES"
    ]
})

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`)
})

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return

    const args = message.content.split(/\s+/)
    
    const commandName = args.shift().substring(prefix.length)

    if(commandName == "say"){

        const messageContent = args.join(" ")

        message.channel.send(messageContent)
        message.delete()
    }
})

client.login(TOKEN)
```

Comment: This question seems to be about JavaScript, not Java. They are completely different languages. Please fix the tags used.

Comment: Tags edited ([java] replaced with [javascript]).

Comment: It looks like `args.shift().substring(prefix.length)` returns 'ay' not 'say'. I recommend trying `args.shift().substring(prefix.length-1)`

Comment: I figured out the issue, and managed to get it to delete the message containing the command!

Is there any way for me to be able to restrict the usage to two separate user IDs?

Answer (score 0):

You could take an approach like:

Include configuration options in a json file like:
`config.json`

```json
{
    "developersId": ["...", "..."]
}
```

Then in your command:

```js
const { developersId } = require("./config.json");

// ...
if (developersId.includes(message.author.id) {
   //...
}
```